# React native Keyboard and touch events

Tags: javascript, keyboard, react-native

The given task here is to begin app with blinking cursor in the center of screen and keyboard hidden, then after clicking anywhere on the white space keyboard should appear like this:

[image: link]

I tried couple of things, but none of them was workiing, so is there any way to do this?
Here is the part of code I've came up whith already

```
 return ( 

  <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}
  scrollEnabled={false}>

  <View 
  style={{
  position: 'absolute',
  right: 0, 
  left:0, 
  bottom: this.state.visibleHeight*1.5-this.state.height*0.5
  }}>

  <TextInput

  autoFocus={true}          
  {...this.props}
  multiline={true}

  style={[styles.input, {height: Math.max(35, this.state.height)}]}

  onChange={(event) => {
      this.setState({
        text: event.nativeEvent.text,
        height: event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height,
      });
    }}

  onChangeText={(text) => {
        this.setState({text});
      }}>

      <Text style={styles.input}>{parts}</Text>
    </TextInput>  
      </View>

       <View style={{position: 'absolute',                        
                    right: 20, 
                    bottom: this.state.countHeight+10
                   }}>
         <Text style={{color: limiterColor}}>{limiter}</Text>
      </View>

  </ScrollView>

);
```

https://rnplay.org/apps/sSKINg

link to the full app

Comment: Hey, i would recommend not to try something like this. There is no documentation about properties that allow to do not show the keyboard while your TextInput is focused. Either in docs or in inline comments. Didn't even find something like that for Objective-C. Easy solution: Emulate your on cursor while textfield is not focused.

Comment: Thank, you. That kind of solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { cross, wifi } from "@assets";
import { navigate } from "@services";
import { RF, Typography } from "@theme";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useTheme } from "@react-navigation/native";
import {
  TextInput,
  View,
  Text,
  InteractionManager,
  Touchable,
} from "react-native";
import {
  CurveHeader,
  AppText,
  Wrapper,
  ErrorImageWrapper,
  ErrorText,
} from "@components";
import {
  setKeybaordResetTime,
  setKeybaordTouched,
  setOrderData,
  store,
} from "@redux";
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
var currencyFormatter = require("currency-formatter");

const EnterAmount = ({ navigation }: any) => {
  const language = useSelector((state: any) => state.root.user.languageType);
  const inputRef: any = useRef();
  const myTheme: any = useTheme();
  const colorTheme = myTheme.colors;
  const dispatch: any = useDispatch();
  const styles = useStyles(colorTheme);
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState<any>("");
  const [errorText, setErrorText] = useState("");

 useEffect(() => {
    let timeout: any = null;
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener("focus", () => {
      focusInputWithKeyboard();
    });`enter code here`
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      unsubscribe;
    };
  }, [navigation]);
  const focusInputWithKeyboard = () => {
    InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    });
  };

  const handleKeyPress = () => {
    dispatch(setKeybaordResetTime(0));
    setKeybaordTouched(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setKeybaordTouched(false);
    }, 500); // set the delay time here
  };
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <View style={styles.view}>
        <AppText
          medium
    
          title={
             "Enter Refund Amount" 
          }
          size={Typography.FONTS.SIZE.LARGE}
        />
          <TextInput
            value={amount}
            ref={inputRef}
            numberOfLines={1}
            autoFocus
            caretHidden={true}
            keyboardType="decimal-pad"
            onSubmitEditing={onClick}
            onChangeText={(text) => handleValueChange(text)}
            style={{
              maxWidth: "85%",
              color: "transparent",
            }}
          />
      </View>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
export default EnterAmount;
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).